# Can not run jupyter cell

Tags: python

I am learning python and faced with some unstable work of jupyter. Yesterday I was able to run my code in notebook but today I can not.

Could you please point out what I should to check out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my antivirus blocks me to use it.